# Validity after leaving France of the "Carte de séjour membre de famille d'un citoyen de l'union"

Tags: france, eu-citizens, eu-spouses

Assume a European Union citizen who is not a citizen of France has moved to France for a period longer than 90 days, with his or her spouse.  The spouse is not an EU citizen, and has received a *carte de séjour «membre de la famille d'un citoyen de l'Union»* with a validity of five years.

The couple leave France after a year.  Three years later, they return.  Is the *carte de séjour* still valid?

If not, when did it lose its validity, and why?